# Display data through ajax using codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am new in ajax .did not able to understand how I get my required output. 
I implement the dependent drop down. the problem is that when I chosed area from dropdown than I am not able to display the restaurant of that area. please tell me how I get the restaurant view.

It's my view code

```
<div class="container"id restaurant>


        <table align="centre" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover no-margin"style="width:70%">
            <thread>
                <tr style="width: 56%;">
                    <th>
                        No.
                    </th>
                    <th style="">
                        Restaurant Names
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thread>
            <tbody>
            <?php $i=1;foreach($result as $row){
                ?>
                <tr id="<?php echo $row->restaurant_id; ?>" class="res_id">
                    <th style="">
                        <?php echo  $i++; ?>

                    </th>
                    <th style="">
                        <?php echo $row->restaurant_name; ?>

                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 1%" >
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/BulkRecipe_Controller/bulk_recipe/<?php echo $row->restaurant_id;?>"  class="btn btn-warning" <i class="glyphicon-edit"></i>See Menu</a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

its my controler code

```
     public function get_rests()
    {

        $cit_id = $this->input->post('cit_id');
        $area = $this->input->post('areaID');
        $where = array('city_id'=>$cit_id,'city_area_id'=>$area);

        $data = $this->bulk->select_record('restaurant',$where);
        echo $data = json_encode($data);
}
```

Its script code

```
function get_rests(){

        var city_id = $('#city_id').val();
        var area_id = $("#area_id").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=base_url();?>index.php/Bulk_Controller/get_rests",
            data: {cit_id: city_id,areaID: area_id},
            dataType: "text",
            cache:false,
            success:
                function(data){
                    $('#restaurant').html(data);
                }
        });
    }
```

Its model code

```
function select_record($table, $where = NULL){

    $this->db->select();
    if($where)
        $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Its front end view after select the area

[image]

Comment: where is your modal??

Comment: print the data in controller function, you will get that in ajax `success()`

Comment: you are not return any data form your controller

Comment: @Gautam please take a loook a add the model now

Comment: code if prefect, but ajax call is not getting the response. so print `$data` in controller and open comment for alert() in ajax success.

Comment: i want to return this view data from controller but when  i did it did not show restaurant  .

Comment: @falakhamid and you check the answer below

Comment: I edit my post but the restaurant view  is showing before selecting the area. and after selected the data show in array form

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function get_rests()
 {

    $cit_id = $this->input->post('cit_id');
    $area = $this->input->post('areaID');
    $where = array('city_id'=>$cit_id,'city_area_id'=>$area);

    $data = $this->bulk->select_record('restaurant',$where);
    echo  json_encode($data); // you will get json encoded data in your ajax success then you can parse the json using jquery and get the detail
}
```

Comment: @Saty when i was posting the answer i was not aware that you were also updating. One small difference is that i provided hint to parse the json once they returned because early stage programmer may not know how to play with json in jqery

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the html of the data in the controller and show on the dropdown select.

```
 public function get_rests()
    {

        $cit_id = $this->input->post('cit_id');
        $area = $this->input->post('areaID');
        $where = array('city_id'=>$cit_id,'city_area_id'=>$area);

        $data = $this->bulk->select_record('restaurant',$where);
       $html = 'your result';
  echo $html;

}
```

Now in the ajax part you can do like this;

```
function get_rests(){

        var city_id = $('#city_id').val();
        var area_id = $("#area_id").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=base_url();?>index.php/Bulk_Controller/get_rests",
            data: {cit_id: city_id,areaID: area_id},
            dataType: "text",
            cache:false,
            success:
                function(data){
                    // alert(data);
                    $('#restaurant').html(data);
                }
        });
    }
```

For more how to select and view data using ajax you can check [this Link](http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-insert-and-view-data-without-refreshing-page-using-ajax-and-jquery-in-codeigniter/)